# In C++ I am getting an Error while I am executing my code with get set and constructor methods

Tags: c++, c++11

In my code I am using the get, set and Employee constructor for getting and take the employee data for that I am creating an one .h file and two .cpp file. While executing these files i am getting error.

So my first .h file is emp.h:

```
#include<iostream>
class Employee
{
  private:
  std::string emp_Name,emp_ID,emp_Address;
  public:
  Employee(std::string name, std::string id, std::string address):emp_Name(name),
    emp_ID(id),emp_Address(address)
  {
  }
  void setempname(std::string name);
  void setempid(std::string id);
  void setempage(std::string address);

  std::string getempname();
  std::string getempid();
  std::string getempaddress();
};
```

My first .cpp file is emp.cpp

```
#include "emp.h"
void Employee::setempname(std::string name)
{
        emp_Name=name;
}
void Employee::setempid(std::string id)
{
        emp_ID=id;
}
void Employee::setempage(std::string address)
{
        emp_Address=address;
}

std::string Employee::getempname()
{
        return emp_Name;
}
std::string Employee::getempid()
{
        return emp_ID;
}
std::string Employee::getempaddress()
{
        return emp_Address;
}
```

My second .cpp file is Main.cpp:

```
#include "emp.h"
int main()
{
        Employee emp[2];
        emp[0]= Employee ("Rohi","E345","Clk");
return 0;
}
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
g++ emp.cpp Main.cpp
Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cpp:4:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘Employee::Employee()’
         Employee emp[2];
                       ^
In file included from Main.cpp:1:
emp.h:7:3: note: candidate: ‘Employee::Employee(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’
   Employee(std::string name, std::string id, std::string address):emp_Name(name),
   ^~~~~~~~
emp.h:7:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
emp.h:2:7: note: candidate: ‘Employee::Employee(const Employee&)’
 class Employee
       ^~~~~~~~
emp.h:2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
emp.h:2:7: note: candidate: ‘Employee::Employee(Employee&&)’
emp.h:2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

So Anyone please help me to solve these error.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, no? You need to provide a default constructor.

Comment: `Employee emp[2];` tries to create 2 instances by calling the default constructor, but there is no default constructor

Comment: By default compiler creates default constructor if you don't define your own constructor. In this case you have defined one, that is why you have to define a default one too that does not accept any arguments. Or you can initialize your objects at the moment they get created so use the defined constructor.  Employee emp = Employee ("Rohi","E345","Clk"); should work.

Comment: Add this member method:  `Employee() = default;`

Comment: After Creating the Default constructor my code will works Thanks For Everyone.